# Intuit API OAuth ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200

Tags: api, oauth, coldfusion, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am using [this library for OAuth v1.0](https://github.com/blove/OAuth-1.0) to connect to QuickBooks Online API. I am successfully able to use three legged authentication and get back access tokens. I am also able to do connect to most endpoints with no problem. However, I am having issue connecting to endpoints with URL parameters.

For example, this URL returns with no issue:

`https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/customer/8`

However, this URL returns with SignatureBaseString: *error 401 unAuthorized*.

`//sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query?query=select * from customer`

Am I misunderstanding something about how to access endpoints with URL parameters in OAuth? Any help or insight would be appreciated.

**Working Code:**

```
<cfset oAuthRequest = new com.brianflove.oauth.Request()>
<cfset oAuthConsumer = new com.brianflove.oauth.Consumer()>
<cfset oauthConsumer.setSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)>
<cfset oauthConsumer.setKey(CONSUMER_KEY)>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setMethod("GET")>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setUrl("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/customer/" & randrange(1,8))>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setConsumer(oAuthConsumer)>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setToken(session.token)>

<!---use HMAC-SHA1 signature method--->
<cfset signatureMethod = new com.brianflove.oauth.methods.HmacSha1SignatureMethod()>

<!---sign request--->
<cfset oAuthRequest.signWithSignatureMethod(signatureMethod=signatureMethod)>


<!---POST using request URL--->
<cfset httpRequest = new Http()>
<cfset httpRequest.setUrl(oAuthRequest.getUrl())>
<cfset httpRequest.setMethod(oAuthRequest.getMethod())>
<cfset httpRequest.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value=oAuthRequest.toHeader())>
<cfset httpRequest.addParam(type="header", name="Accept", value="application/json") />
<cfset httpRequest.setCharset("utf-8")>
<cfset httpResult = httpRequest.send().getPrefix()>

<cfdump var="#httpResult.filecontent#">
```

**Not Working Code:**

```
<cfset oAuthRequest = new com.brianflove.oauth.Request()>
<cfset oAuthConsumer = new com.brianflove.oauth.Consumer()>
<cfset oauthConsumer.setSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)>
<cfset oauthConsumer.setKey(CONSUMER_KEY)>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setMethod("GET")>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setUrl("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query?query=select * from customer") />
<cfset oAuthRequest.setConsumer(oAuthConsumer)>
<cfset oAuthRequest.setToken(session.token)>

<!---use HMAC-SHA1 signature method--->
<cfset signatureMethod = new com.brianflove.oauth.methods.HmacSha1SignatureMethod()>

<!---sign request--->
<cfset oAuthRequest.signWithSignatureMethod(signatureMethod=signatureMethod)>

<!---POST using request URL--->
<cfset httpRequest = new Http()>
<cfset httpRequest.setUrl(oAuthRequest.getUrl())>
<cfset httpRequest.setMethod(oAuthRequest.getMethod())>
<cfset httpRequest.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value=oAuthRequest.toHeader())>
<cfset httpRequest.addParam(type="header", name="Accept", value="application/json") />
<cfset httpRequest.setCharset("utf-8")>
<cfset httpResult = httpRequest.send().getPrefix()>

<cfdump var="#httpResult.filecontent#">
```

**Error Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse time="2016-12-01T06:12:00.999-08:00" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
        <Error code="3200">
            <Message>message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401</Message>
            <Detail>SignatureBaseString: GET&amp;https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F123145723805019%2Fquery&amp;oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdTVZH2CtDAXewG1YQKQYzUssYH%26oauth_nonce%3D420ADB0BF9EF309B785C531EEE8A7AAF%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1480601520%26oauth_token%3Dqyprd5g2WEiaxaVyI3MqeXqRvxvi26cXuauyMtFQaMZHdjVT%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26query%3Dselect%2520%252A%2520from%2520customer</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Comment: OAuth and the like are very picky about signatures. Just a guess, but I suspect the signature is not being calculated correctly when query string parameters are included directly in the URL. Instead, try adding the parameters to the `oAuthRequest` object, via `addParameter()`.

Comment: @Leigh thanks - I think I have tried that before, but just to make sure I tried it again using <cfset oAuthRequest.setUrl("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query") />
 <cfset oAuthRequest.addParameter(key="query", value="select * from customer") /> and got same response

Comment: (Edit): Okay, I am out of ideas for the moment, but will give it a try later when I get a chance. In the mean time, can you post the URL for the QB docs showing the "customer" example you are trying to duplicate?

Comment: https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=Customer                    and                https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/customer

Comment: I know this is a little old-ish. Did you ever figure it out? Struggling with what appears to be the same issue. (Although, I'm working in Ruby.)

Comment: @jvillian. sorry no solution was found. good luck

Comment: Struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Me too, @user1124236...

Answer (score 0):

Encode the query statement before passing it into the URL.

Use the below method to perform the encoding:

```
<cffunction name="encodePercent" returntype="string" access="public"
            description="RFC 3986 encoding - keep [ALPHA, DIGIT, '-', '.', '_', '~'], %-encode the rest -> decoding '~', correctly encoding spaces('+') and '*'">
    <cfargument name="sValue"       required="true" type="string" hint="value to encode">
    <cfargument name="sEncoding"    required="false" type="string" default="UTF-8" hint="encoding">
    <cfset var sResult = "">
    <!--- using javacast to call the appropriate encode method --->
    <cfif Len(arguments.sValue)>
        <cfset sResult = CreateObject("java","java.net.URLEncoder").
                            encode(JavaCast("String",arguments.sValue), JavaCast("String",arguments.sEncoding))>
        <cfset sResult = Replace(sResult,"+","%20","all")>
        <cfset sResult = Replace(sResult,"*","%2A","all")>
        <cfset sResult = Replace(sResult,"%7E","~","all")>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn sResult>
</cffunction>
```

You can keep the default value of the "sEncoding" argument as is.

Comment: thanks but not working. I tried the following <cfset urlparam = encodePercent("select * from customer") /> <cfset oAuthRequest.setUrl("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query?query=" & urlparam & "&minorversion=4") />   It creates the URL to look like this: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query?query=select%20%2A%20from%20customer&minorversion=4

Comment: If you examine the rest of the generated http request, how does it compare to their tool? Ignoring the charset, it seemed to have the right pieces, and the Auth header looked similar - though the "oath_xxx" parameters seemed to be in a slightly different order (not sure if that matters).

Comment: @Leigh if I use their API explorer it shows the following Request URI: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145723805019/query?query=select%20%2A%20from%20customer&minorversion=4 Request Headers: Accept: application/json
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="************",oauth_nonce="77bb5009-69b1-4aad-ae3c-cb9dc66433d7",oauth_consumer_key="************",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1480686014",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="w1Z%2FHSG5ETeynZ4DN2RUr%2BTFOpQ%3D"
intuit_tid: idg-ajrnbybr1pfzjregh1gzsjo2-5535777
User-Agent: APIExplorer

Comment: @Leigh It also works successfully using the Postman chrome app. I am unsure if the order of the variables in Authorization matter..I don't think so

Comment: Probably not, but some API's are picky so it was worth mentioning. Try examining the successful PostMan request and http headers to the those generated by the CFC to see what looks different. You can always modify the CFC to use the same values if needed (ie dynamic stuff, timestamp, nonce, etcetera...)

Comment: Took the headers from Postman (using same token) and copied them into Authorization header in code. The one that has no url parameters worked so the headers must be correct. Looking into the Signature string more or the URL.

Comment: W/Postman can you see the [raw string](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2015/02/19/oauth-for-intuit-demystified) (before it is signed)? Comparing that to the one generated in CF would tell you if the problem is a difference in the value being signed or something in the signing process.

Comment: I do not see a way to see the string in Post Man or in the API explorer.